# Apache RewriteRule discards SetInputFilter DEFLATE config directive

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-deflate

I have the following (simplified) folder/file structure:

```
/.htaccess
/test.php
/api/web/index.php
```

And the following directive in apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        SetInputFilter DEFLATE
   </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I am sending a POST request with a gzipped body with the appropiated headers:

```
POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.248
Authorization: Bearer ed717c077e4bf81201196011adb457731b24e19d
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

And I have the following config for the **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) api/web/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

The issue is, if I post to `/test.php`, everything works as expected, the body is deflated and I can access decompressed contents just right.

However if I post to something that gets redirected (`/api/` or `/api/v1/project`) the `index.php` script does not get the body decompressed.

I think it must be related to the `RewriteRule` directive ignoring the `SetInputFilter` directive, but, how can I avoid this situation?

I tried to add the `SetInputFilter` directive directly in the .htaccess without solving the issue (may be it was not in the right place?).

Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you have set `AllowOverride All` in your virtual host config?

Comment: @HalfCrazed AllowOverride All is active. And I think it is working properly because the redirection I defined in the .htaccess is working but ignoring the SetInputFilter directive that it is in the apache.conf file.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well. May I know whether anyone has come up with a solution?

Comment: @FrederickZhang I posted the issue on Apache mailing list (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/201707.mbox/%3C12d7b54a-1bac-448b-168f-87351d0452d3%40ono.com%3E) and forums (https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=7686) without any success. I opted to deflate the body myself but I am still confident a solution from Apache will come sometime in the future :)

Comment: What is `/api/web/` ? A known *CMS* or something of your own ? Indeed, `POST` data is passed along with the request when rewriting and it should be the same for decompressed contents, I guess. Also, did you check your server logs ? You may find some interesting things there

Comment: @JustinIurman I don't think that's something related. You can have a basic setup which contains only an `index.php` and a `.htaccess` to rewrite all requests to `index.php` to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @JustinIurman I prepared a test suite but I could not attach the link to download them as I was too newbie in StackOverflow. Now I can, https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfduw81flnvy1ik/test-suite.zip?dl=0

Comment: Found a solution (see `Update 2 (working)` section in my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, there is a problem. The first thing I did to investigate deeper was to log traces of concerned modules (`rewrite`, `filter` and `deflate`).

**mod_rewrite logs** were OK, nothing suspicious there. To make sure everything was really OK, I looked at the very last version of its [source code](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c). And again, nothing suspicious regarding encoding/decoding (nor http request/response headers, more generally).

So I started thinking the problem may come from either `filter` or `deflate` module, even if it may also come from somewhere else. To confirm/infirm what I thought, I looked at those modules logs. Quickly, I was able to see a difference between the two test cases: with or without `mod_rewrite` involved.

## mod_rewrite not involved

```
mod_deflate.c(1421): [client 127.0.0.1:53000] AH01393: Zlib: Inflated 35 to 41 : URL /test.php
mod_filter.c(188): [client 127.0.0.1:53000] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' matched
```

I took this one as a reference to compare the next case below

## mod_rewrite involved

```
mod_filter.c(188): [client 127.0.0.1:53002] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' matched
```

Interesting. Actually, it looked like `mod_deflate` was the problem. I suspected its action was **after** the right moment. That's the reason why you don't see it in action, here, in this case.

## Solution

So far, so good. So... what ? Well, a quick search on the known bugs list of Apache, with keywords `mod_deflate too late`, gave me by chance [what I was searching for](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=mod_deflate%20too%20late). This ticket called [mod_deflate adjusts the headers "too late"](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54255), states the following:

> When mod_deflate is used to inflate, it must adjust the request
>   headers (e.g. it needs to remove the "Content-Length" header and
>   adjust the "Content-Encoding" header).
>
> Currently mod_deflate adjusts the headers when the request body is
>   read. But this is too late. For example, if a content generator module
>   needs to look at the request headers before reading the request body,
>   the content generator module "sees" the old (unmodified) headers.
>
> mod_deflate should adjust the headers in an early stage, for example
>   in a fixup hook (ap_hook_fixups).

**Eureka** ! This is exactly the problem we're facing. Now, good news is there is a patch to overcome this issue. Bad news: it is not yet reviewed/accepted/merged in available versions.

**You have the choice**:

1. Apply this patch and recompile your server. It should work because the all thing makes sense. **But, be careful**... this may introduce other bugs/holes (that's sometimes the case, even when reviewed/accepted)
2. Wait for it to be included in available versions (maybe a long time, considering the ticket date). By then, use your custom deflate with php.

## Update

Just tried to apply the patch and recompile `mod_deflate`. Looks like it's on the right track: it eats `Content-Encoding` header. Anyway, `Content-Length` is still there. Result: no yet decompressed. So, there is still something to do and adapt, but the problem is definitely in that area.

## Update 2 (working)

I managed to make it work, finally. Here is the patch I applied to Apache (`httpd version 2.4.34`):

```
diff --git a/modules/filters/mod_deflate.c b/modules/filters/mod_deflate.c
index 1428460..cc8c0cb 100644
--- a/modules/filters/mod_deflate.c
+++ b/modules/filters/mod_deflate.c
@@ -1099,10 +1099,10 @@ static apr_status_t deflate_in_filter(ap_filter_t *f,

         if (!ctx) {
             /* only work on main request/no subrequests */
-            if (!ap_is_initial_req(r)) {
+            /*if (!ap_is_initial_req(r)) {
                 ap_remove_input_filter(f);
                 return ap_get_brigade(f->next, bb, mode, block, readbytes);
-            }
+            }*/

             /* We can't operate on Content-Ranges */
             if (apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "Content-Range") != NULL) {
```

Actually, I made `mod_deflate` handle sub-requests too. I'm not sure it's not gonna break some other modules, but it works for your use case (it's more a proof of concept). Anyway, I proposed my patch on the ticket mentioned above. Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, excellent answer! It's sad tho that such an ancient issue hasn't got fixed in Apache. I guess `mod_deflate` was mainly designed for WebDAV and didn't get thoroughly tested in different scenarios as few clients actually support request payload compression. I reckon it's better for me to conquer the issue directly in my code like OP at least for now.

Comment: Yes, it's sad. Welcome to the open-source world ! But it has also many advantages so let's be happy. For your solution, indeed it's more prudent to wait for an official change in apache releases. I restarted the thread (ticket) by submitting my patch, let's see if something moves. I hope it'll get back to life soon.

Comment: @JustinIurman wow, good job, you have just hit the nail in the head.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm glad I brought both of you an explanation on this very old problem. Unanswered questions and unsolved issues are painful.